# django factory boy test gives __str__ returned non-string

Tags: python, django, factory-boy

I'm adjusting tests to use factory boy instances instead of models.objects.create(..)

It's going well, but now I've run into an error and I can't seem to find the source. Can anyone help?

models.py

```
class Regelset(models.Model):  # todo: statussen?
    # todo: koppeling productiebestanden
    # todo: xml inlezen

    bon = models.ForeignKey(Bon)
    toepassing = models.ForeignKey(Toepassing)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)

    naam = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, help_text="naam")
    originelen = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=0, null=True, blank=True, help_text="originelen")
    oplage = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=0, null=True, blank=True, help_text="oplage")

    breedte_in_cm = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=3, null=True, blank=True,
                                        help_text="breedte in cm")
    hoogte_in_cm = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=3, null=True, blank=True, help_text="hoogte in cm")

    # bedoeld om een extra formaat door te geven (bedoeld voor Repro items)
    breedte_in_cm2 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=3, null=True, blank=True,
                                         help_text="breedte in cm")
    hoogte_in_cm2 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=3, null=True, blank=True,
                                        help_text="hoogte in cm")

    strekkende_meters = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    korting = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    korting_invoer = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True, help_text="korting")
    type_korting = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=MenusGlobals.type_korting_choices, blank=True,
                                    help_text="type korting")
    # nesting is een samengesteld veld van de printregel en mediaregel wat gezet wordt. Queries gaan niet over een
    # berekend veld
    nesting = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)

    omslag_dubbelzijdig = models.BooleanField(help_text="omslag dubbelzijdig", default=False)
    binnenwerk_dubbelzijdig = models.BooleanField(help_text="binnenwerk dubbelzijdig", default=False)
    binnenwerk_kleur = models.BooleanField(help_text="binnenwerk kleur", default=False)
    omslag_kleur = models.BooleanField(help_text="omslag kleur", default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.naam

    def get_verkoopprijs_ex_kort(self):
        return self.sum_gerelateerde_regelwaardes('verkoopprijs_ex_kort')

    def get_verkoopprijs_ex_kort_incl_productprijs(self):
        return self.sum_gerelateerde_regelwaardes('verkoopprijs_ex_kort_incl_productprijs')

    def get_verkoopprijs_incl_kort(self):
        return self.sum_gerelateerde_regelwaardes('verkoopprijs_incl_kort')

    def get_basisprijs(self):
        return self.sum_gerelateerde_regelwaardes('basisprijs')

    def get_korting(self):
        return self.sum_gerelateerde_regelwaardes('korting')

    def get_aantal(self):
        return self.originelen * self.oplage

    def get_oppervlakte_m2_per_stuk(self):
        if self.toepassing.afmeting_verplicht():
            return self.breedte_in_cm / 100 * self.hoogte_in_cm / 100
        return 0

    def sum_gerelateerde_regelwaardes(self, fieldname):
        # ondersteunende functie om alle getallen vanuit een veld uit de regel tabel bij elkaar op te tellen
        waardelijst = self.regel_set.all().aggregate(models.Sum(fieldname))  # output = {'<fieldname>_sum': waarde}
        return invoer_is_check_is_value(waardelijst.get('{0}__sum'.format(fieldname)), check=None, value=0)
```

Factories.py

```
import factory
from . import models


class ArtikelFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Artikel


class ToepassingFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Toepassing


class ToepassingRegelFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = models.ToepassingsRegel

    toepassing = factory.SubFactory(ToepassingFactory)


class ProductFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Product

    toepassing = factory.SubFactory(ToepassingFactory)


class RelatieFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Relatie

    firmanaam = "Nepper"
    code = "neppe"


class ProjectFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Project

    relatie = factory.SubFactory(RelatieFactory)


class BonFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Bon

    project = factory.SubFactory(ProjectFactory)


class RegelsetFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Regelset            

    bon = factory.SubFactory(BonFactory)
    product = factory.SubFactory(ProductFactory)
    naam = "naam"
    get_oppervlakte_m2_per_stuk = factory.PostGenerationMethodCall('get_oppervlakte_m2_per_stuk')
    get_aantal = factory.PostGenerationMethodCall('get_aantal')
```

Tests.py

```
from django.test import TestCase

from decimal import Decimal

from .nesting import Nesting, FormaatError
from .import factories


class NestingTests(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.regelsetlijst = [factories.RegelsetFactory.create(naam="naam", originelen=1, oplage=3, breedte_in_cm=50, hoogte_in_cm=50),
                              factories.RegelsetFactory.create(naam="naam", originelen=1, oplage=1, breedte_in_cm=50, hoogte_in_cm=200),
                              factories.RegelsetFactory.create(naam="naam", originelen=1, oplage=1, breedte_in_cm=100, hoogte_in_cm=100)]


    def test_get_nesting_1_vel(self):
        self.assertEqual(Nesting(self.regelsetlijst, 1.37, 50, 0.5, maak_html=False).start_nesting(), (round(Decimal(3.52), 2), round(Decimal(2.75), 2)))

    def test_get_nesting_formaaterror(self):
        self.assertEqual(Nesting(self.regelsetlijst, 1.37, 2.5, 0.5, maak_html=False).start_nesting(), FormaatError)

    def test_get_nesting_2_vel(self):
        self.assertEqual(Nesting(self.regelsetlijst, 1.37, 3, 0.5, maak_html=False).start_nesting(), (round(Decimal(4.51), 2), round(Decimal(2.75), 2)))
```

Traceback:

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\SjoerdvanPoelgeest\Desktop\systeem\calculator\test_nesting.py", line 11, in setUp
    self.regelsetlijst = [factories.RegelsetFactory.create(naam="naam", originelen=1, oplage=3, breedte_in_cm=50, hoogte_in_cm=50),
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\factory\base.py", line 558, in create
    attrs = cls.attributes(create=True, extra=kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\factory\base.py", line 400, in attributes
    force_sequence=force_sequence,
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\factory\containers.py", line 228, in build
    return stub.__fill__()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\factory\containers.py", line 83, in __fill__
    res[attr] = getattr(self, attr)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\factory\containers.py", line 105, in __getattr__
    val = val.evaluate(self, self.__containers)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\factory\containers.py", line 160, in evaluate
    containers=containers,
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\factory\declarations.py", line 298, in evaluate
    return self.generate(sequence, obj, create, defaults)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\factory\declarations.py", line 385, in generate
    return subfactory.simple_generate(create, **params)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\factory\base.py", line 645, in simple_generate
    return cls.generate(strategy, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\factory\base.py", line 612, in generate
    return action(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\factory\base.py", line 558, in create
    attrs = cls.attributes(create=True, extra=kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\factory\base.py", line 400, in attributes
    force_sequence=force_sequence,
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\factory\containers.py", line 228, in build
    return stub.__fill__()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\factory\containers.py", line 85, in __fill__
    self.__log_ctx, utils.log_pprint(kwargs=res),
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\factory\utils.py", line 119, in log_pprint
    for key, value in kwargs.items()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\factory\utils.py", line 119, in <listcomp>
    for key, value in kwargs.items()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\factory\utils.py", line 103, in _safe_repr
    obj_repr = repr(obj)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 496, in __repr__
    u = six.text_type(self)
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)
```

Comment: I don't understand the last two lines of your factory code - where you assign a value to the get... methods.  What purpose does this serve?

Comment: Using a debugger (or just with a print); Can you check what 'key' and 'value' are here: "line 119, in <listcomp> for key, value in kwargs.items()".

Comment: @Dashdrum it let's you use model methods in the factory instance. see: http://factoryboy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference.html

Comment: output for line 119, has some empty values, But I don't know how to fix it. This is deep in the factory boy code and doesn't seem the right place. I think I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Could the problem be in on of the sub factories being called?

Comment: Could be, I'll put the full factories.py in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
def __str__(self):
    return '%s' % self.naam
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work.. I've put in the models.py as wel as in the factories.py and some input variations.

btw: what is difference between this and just a self.naam return? The output is the same.

Comment: Not the OP, but '%s' % None returns 'None' (as in the string 'None') which is a string, unlike just None

Comment: Sorry, Ondrej. It is the correct answer. New morning, new insights. 
With the comment of Foon in mind, I've now put your answer in all model.classes where needed and not just in de 'regelset' class. And now it works! (sort of, but the errors that now appear, I can handle;-) )

Comment: I'll only reform it to:    
def __str__(self):
        return '{0}'.format(self.naam)
What does the same, but is something I'm more used to